# how to add radioButton & CheckBox in DataGridView? in C#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

how to add radioButton & CheckBox in DataGridView? and only one checkBox should be selected at a time and how to add event onCheck or OnSelected event?

Answer (score 1):

add datagrid view -> go to properties

find property--> Columns (Collections)

Add Column ----->        Name the column || Type: Select checkbox, button, image or link  || Give column header name

To select single only: false the datagrid property "multiselect"

Click on event button in property to bind the Events.